# TFS2012 : SQL to get User's project list to which he has access

Tags: sql, tfs, report

I'm trying to create a report using report builder which should contain all TFS users and projects to which they have access. Get this information from the Work Item history it's not the way i'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this from SQL as permissions are not pushed to the Warehouse. You can get this from the API. If you retrieve a ProjectInfo object it should have a HasAccess property that is set to true if you have permission.

To find out if another user has access you will likely need to query the Security Store.

Comment: Hello MrHinsh, thank you for quick answer. I know that information about permissions is not stored in Warehouse, that's why i'm trying to query Configuration DB. 
But i cannot find a join between Users and their Projects

Comment: Querying the Configuration DB directly is not supported or recommended. Use the API.